# How to write this code cleaner, without repetition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  $("#yl").click(function(){updateYear("sub")});
  $("#yr").click(function(){updateYear("add")});
  $("#ml").click(function(){updateMonth("sub")});
  $("#mr").click(function(){updateMonth("add")});
  $("#dl").click(function(){updateDay("sub")});
  $("#dr").click(function(){updateDay("add")});
```

Is there a way to write this code cleaner, smarter without repetitions?

Comment: Probably post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Use a class name....

Comment: I suggest use a common class for those clickable elements and use the `id` and an object to get  the parameter of `updateYear`: `var obj = {yl: "sub", yr: "add", ...}; $(".common-class").click(function(){ updateYear(obj[this.id]); });`

Comment: Not sure what you would get by changing it. If you change how your functions are declared you could.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly unclean our unsmart about this code. It's clear what's going on, and that's extremely important for maintenance/debugging purposes. You might be able to replace `function(){updateYear("sub")})` with `updateYear.bind(null, "sub")` (or `updateYear.bind(this, "sub")`) and so forth, but that's about it, I think.

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right, Einstein said "Make it as simple as possible, but not simplier". Thank you all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mkobit It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a close reason. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (the code would likely need to be expanded from the current form, lest it appear as stub code). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Thanks @SamOnela for the explanation and the link, I'll keep it mind next time I see questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your elements a bit, you could do something like this:

```
<button id='yr' data-type='update' data-date-part='year' data-date-action='add'>
```

Then you create an update function that starts off like this:

```
function update() {
  const el = $(this);
  const datePart = el.attr('data-date-part');
  const dateAction = el.attr('data-date-action');

  // do your logic to update the date based on what part and action
}
```

Then your click handler just needs to be:

```
$('button[data-type="update"]').click(update);
```

I forgot to mention, that newer versions of jquery will also let you just use the `.data()` function instead of spelling out the full `data-` attribute

Comment: And now you've replaced what is fairly straightforward JS with logic that's obscure and split between the JS and the HTML, and furthermore made the HTML dependent on the structure of the JS. Doesn't seem to me like a smart thing to do.

Comment: @TedHopp It is personal opinion what is better.... One things this is better, another thinks what OP had was better. I can think of two other ways of doing it that might be better or worse. That is why programming is great because we can do whatever we like.

Comment: @TedHopp sure, there's different ways to optimize things, and different preferences.  I have seen plenty of arguments in both directions.  I do think you're over-stating the amount of indirection involved here, but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine as it stands as it is very clear what is happening.

If you really want to do it differently, then you should probably also modify your function(s) and look into HTML attributes. It all depends what you are actually doing in those functions.

If for instance you want the user to enter a date just by pressing add/sub buttons, then the basics could look like this:

```js
$('.change-value').click(updateDatePart);

function updateDatePart() {
    // Read current date
    var dateParts = $.map($(this).closest(".dateinput").find(".part-value"), function (span) {
        return +$(span).text();
    });
    // Which part of the date needs incrementing/decrementing?
    var part = $(this).closest('.part').index();
    // Apply change to that part
    dateParts[part] += $(this).data("inc");
    // Create a date with this
    var date = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[2]);
    // Get the parts for the new date (which may have resolved some overflow)
    dateParts = [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate()];
    // Output the result
    $('.part-value').each(function (i, elem) {
        $(elem).text(dateParts[i]);
    });
}
```

```css
.change-value { font-size: 50% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dateinput">
    <span class="part">
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="-1">-</button>
        <span class="part-value">2017</span>
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="1">+</button>
    </span>-
    <span class="part">
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="-1">-</button>
        <span class="part-value">12</span>
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="1">+</button>
    </span>-
    <span class="part">
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="-1">-</button>
        <span class="part-value">24</span>
        <button class="change-value" data-inc="1">+</button>
    </span>
</span>
```